# 2007 Access DB Y/N format change to check mark in Excel - export?

Tags: formatting, ms-access-2007

regarding the format for 2007 Access DB export to 2007 Excel....

In Access, I have a Y/N column yet I'd rather format the Y to a checked format in Excel and leave the N blank. I can do N to blank but the Y to checked is what I am stumped. Is there a way to that? Query? Export? However?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the following and it worked for me. For test data in the table [YesNo]

```
ID  YesNoField
--  ----------
 1  False
 2  True
```

if I export the following saved query to Excel

```sql
SELECT YesNo.ID, IIf([YesNoField],ChrW(10003),"") AS IsTrue
FROM [YesNo];
```

I get

[image: Excel.png]